# Change value in if-statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement

in my script, i would like do a comparison between two variable.
Example :

```
if ($1 -eq $2) {$checkbox.checked=$true}
```

My problem is the the value of checkbox.checked doesn't changed.
Why ? It's impossible execute a commande in the "then" ?

I'm sorry for my english and I really hope someone can help me.

Yohann.

Comment: Can you provide more code? we can't really help you based on this single line.

Comment: Your code should work. The error must be somewhere else in your code. We need to see the rest of your script to help you find the error.

Comment: Run the code the in PowerShell ISE. Put a breakpoint on that line and see what is in $1 and $2. Either that or do something like `write-host $1 $2` to see what is in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
}
#start
#we check ram freee
$machine = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem
$ram = [int64]$machine.TotalPhysicalMemory/1MB
$ram2 = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
$ramfree = [int64]$ram2.FreePhysicalMemory/1024
$txtbox_ram.Text = [math]::round($ramfree,1) 
$rampercent = $ramfree/$ram*100
[int]$intram = $rampercent.value
$txtbox_ramtotale.Text = [math]::round($rampercent)

#we check space disk used in C:
$space = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk
$spacec = $space |ForEach-Object {$_.size/1MB}
$spacefreec = $space | ForEach-Object {$_.freespace/1MB}
$txtbox_disk.text =[math]::round($spacec[0],1)

$spacediskpercent = ($spacefreec[0])/($spacec[0])*100
[int]$intdisk = $spacediskpercent.value

$txtbox_diskpercent.Text = [math]::round($spacediskpercent)

#test if space disk use < 90 then checkbox = true
$seuil = [int]10
if ($intram.value -le $seuil.value) 
{$chkbox.Checked = $true}

#test if space disk use < 90 then checkbox = true   
[int]$seuil = 90
if ($intdisk -gt $seuil)
{$chkbox.Checked = $true}

}
```

if it's not clear, i would compare 2 integer and if it's true, so check checkbox.
Thank's for help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to get the values from PowerShell variables with `$variable.value` which does not work.

So executing this:

```
[int]$intram = $rampercent.value
```

Does not work. `$intram` will have the value of `0`

Instead, just use the variable like this without the ".value":

```
[int]$intram = $rampercent
```

Now `$intram` contains the correct number

This also means that you have to change this:

```
[int]$intdisk = $spacediskpercent.value
```

To this:

```
[int]$intdisk = $spacediskpercent
```

And the if statement that sets the checkbox from:

```
if ($intram.value -le $seuil.value)
```

To:

```
if ($intram -le $seuil)
```